# Reuse query from union's select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query that follows this pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  a
    FROM    b
) `firstQuery`

UNION

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  b
    FROM    c
) `secondQuery`
```

And I want `secondQuery` to exclude rows from `firstQuery`, however

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  a
    FROM    b
) `firstQuery`
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  b
    FROM    c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM `firstQuery`
    )
) `secondQuery`
```

doesn't work.
Can someone point me in the right direction? How do I reuse results of a subquery?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Have you heard of CTEs?

Comment: You post a broken query without telling us what you want to accomplish.  How do you expect us to help you???  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Shawn - CTEs were only introduced in MySQL 8.0. But you are right on point here.

Comment: `UNION` already removes duplicates from the result set, so you'll only get results from 'secondquery' that weren't already returned by 'firstquery'

Comment: @Eric I thought the snippet illustrates the idea clearly. Two unioned SELECT queries. I want to reuse the first one inside of NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UNION already removes duplicates from the result set, so you'll only get results from 'secondquery' that weren't already returned by 'firstquery' – @Aaron Dietz

Aaron was right on point. Thanks!